# Como fazer para a largura e a altura de um elemento partirem do centro e expandirem para a esquerda e direita?

Tags: html, css

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Ripple effect</title>
    <style>

        body {
            margin: 0;
        }

        #button {
            width: 170px;
            height: 70px;
            background: #4cacaf;
            color: #ffffff;
            border: none;
            border-radius: 5px;
            outline: none;
            font-size: 20px;
            font-weight: bold;
            cursor: pointer;
            position: relative;
            overflow: hidden;
            
        }
        
        #ripple {
            width: 0;
            width: 0;
            border-radius: 50%;
            background: rgb(46, 253, 219);
            position: absolute;
            opacity: 0.4;
        }

        @keyframes animatedRipple {
            0% {
                width: 0;
                height: 0;
            }

            100% {
                width: 100px;
                height: 100px;
            }
        }
        
        </style>
</head>
<body>

    <button id="button">CLICK ME
        <div id="ripple"></div>
    </button>

    <script>
        
        let button = document.querySelector("#button");
        let ripple = document.querySelector("#ripple");

        button.onmousemove = () => {
            let x = event.pageX;
            let y = event.pageY;

            button.onclick = () => {
                ripple.style.left = `${x - 50}px`;
                ripple.style.top = `${y - 40}px`;
                ripple.style.animation = "animatedRipple 0.4s linear";
            };

            button.addEventListener("animationend", () => {
                ripple.style.animation = "none";
            });
        };

    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Criei um botão com efeito *Ripple Effect*, mas o problema é que quando clico no botão o *ripple* não parte do centro e vai se expandindo, ele parte da esquerda e vai se expandindo para a direita, que nem esse pequeno exemplo de baixo.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
    
        div {
            background: red;
            border-radius: 50%;
            animation: animatedDiv 1s linear infinite;
        }

        @keyframes animatedDiv {
            0% {
                width: 0;
                height: 0;
            }

            100% {
                width: 100px;
                height: 100px;
            }
        }
    
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <div></div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

a animação da `div` parte da esquerda e vai para a direita, como fazer para a largura e altura dela partir do centro e se expandir para a esquerda e direita, como se fosse uma explosão?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Acho que você pode conseguir este efeito deixando a margem negativa, tente isto.

[Aqui](https://codepen.io/JucVictor/pen/RwwogaL) tem um link para o codepen.io onde você pode brincar um pouco.

```html
<!doctype html>
    <html lang="pt-br">
    <head>
       <meta charset="utf-8">
       <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
       <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
       <title>Document</title>
       <style>
            :root {
              /* Não retire o px do 0 */
             --margem-inicial: 0px;
             --tamanho-expansao: 100px;
             --margem-expansao-calc: calc((var(--margem-inicial) - var(--tamanho-expansao)) / 2);
            }

            div {
                position: relative;
                top: 50vh;
                width: 10px;
                height: 10px;
                background-color: red;
                left: 50vw;
                animation: animation 1s linear infinite;
            }

            @keyframes animation {
                0% {
                width: 10px; 
                height: 10px;
              }

                100% {
                width: 110px; 
                height: 110px;
                margin: var(--margem-expansao-calc);
              }
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div></div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Era isso mesmo amigo, obrigado, ajudo muito!